# Is there any way this disk might have some data on it?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1

I'm a bit confused here.. is this just empty space, no partition?

Why are all the options greyed out?

How do I add a parition without using a 3rd party tool?

If I can't, would a 3rd party tool like minitool partition software let me do it?

I can't seem to find some files that I  thought I had on a USB drive, they are not on the other 3 (I can read all those). However it is possible that this is a drive I cleaned up long ago and therefore blank but I don't understand why it is not possible to add a new partion, format it or anything.

If it is some kind of sneaky invisible to windows partition of some kind of data, then how can I view it?[image]

Comment: That disk is offline. Use diskpart to [bring it online](http://thetechnologychronicle.blogspot.in/2013/05/use-diskpart-to-make-drives-online.html).

Comment: What software you are using for these extra Explorer buttons? (including pin window button)

Comment: you've got sharp eyes lol... eXtra buttons, it's free.. they have about 10 different buttons to choose from. They are for all windows, not just explorer.. transparent button is quite useful (another similar but less-buttons program is called 4t tray minimizer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need disk part to activate the partition. Just dont click on the partition with the right mouse button and click instead on the left side where "disk2 basic ..." is printed.

Then you should get an contex menu where you should be able to mark the disk as online.